# Passing bot protection during web scraping

Tags: web-scraping

I would appreciate any ideas how to pass bot protection during web scraping
fake user agent doesn't do any good
proxy pool in Scrapy also
timeouts not working (though I never tried really long timeouts, like minutes)

I face blocking in pagination module. If I do direct link pagination or Selenium click or Splash click I immediately get "We detected strange activity from your network"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you haven't mentioned is about download delay and the number of requests per Domain or IP.

Both of these are configured in your settings.py file.  A good tip to avoid getting banned would be to put a download delay of 2 seconds on (as recommended by Scrapy Best Pracices here - https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html).  Personally I also only make 1 request per domain.  Yes this does make scraping a website a far longer process but I'd rather that than risk getting outright banned from the website.

If you have already been banned by a website, it may be permanent.  I got hit by Cloudflare a while ago on a website and whenever I access that website now Cloudflare checks my browser before letting me view the website.  As such Scrapy will only work on that website if I use a rotating proxy pool.

If your proxy pool is timing out, I'd check it is actually working though without knowing what your configuration is I can't offer any tips for debugging.  I would try checking it on a website that does work, or even scrape a website that returns your IP address so you can check your proxy is working.  In addition  I would check for any responses you're getting (503, 504 etc.) when running the spider.